# Changing Azure AD Authority from /tenantID to /common causes 401

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, blazor

I have a Blazor WASM Azure static web app that communicates with an Azure AD protected API running on ASP.NET Core. I had setup Microsoft Account and one-time passcode IDPs.

I could sign in and call protected endpoints on my API - only when signed in - until I had my first Microsoft Account that wasn't in the tenant. They got [AADSTS50020](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/SupportArticles-docs/blob/main/support/azure/active-directory/error-code-AADSTS50020-user-account-identity-provider-does-not-exist.md). The only cause that applied to me was cause 2 (used the wrong endpoint), so I changed my authority from `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<YourTenantNameOrID>` to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common` according to that help page and [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc).

Now every user can sign but we all get 401 unauthorized on protected endpoints.

The **WWW-Authenticate** header is set to `Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"`.

I obviously haven't "tried everything" if one simple change causes everything to break, but I've pored over documentation these past couple days to no avail.

---

Notes:

- The one-time passcode sign-in option went away, and my main MS account is never auto-suggested even though I use it every time.
- My tokens "look" fine, the `aud` is the API client id and the 1 necessary scope is present in `scp`.

---

API manifest

```
    ...
    "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": true,
    "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": false,
    ...
    "oauth2Permissions": [
        {
            "adminConsentDescription": "Allows the app to access the web API on behalf of the signed-in user",
            "adminConsentDisplayName": "Access the API on behalf of a user",
            "id": "<access_as_user scope id>",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "lang": null,
            "origin": "Application",
            "type": "User",
            "userConsentDescription": "Allows this app to access the web API on your behalf",
            "userConsentDisplayName": "Access the API on your behalf",
            "value": "access_as_user"
        }
    ],
    ...
    "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
    ...
```

Client manifest

```
    ...
    "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": true,
    "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true,
    ...
    "requiredResourceAccess": [
        ...
        {
            "resourceAppId": "<api client id>",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "<access_as_user scope id>",
                    "type": "Scope"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    ...
    "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
    ...
```

I can provide additional information, such as configuration code, but I didn't want to start out making the question too long.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the rule of finding the answer shortly after posting on a help board relative to the time spent searching for the answer before posting on the help board reigns supreme.

For anyone who has the same question, my `TenantId` configuration on my API was set to my actual tenant id. Even if your client requests a token from the `common` endpoint, your API needs tenant set to `common` too.

See more:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration